# Rotate in Opera

Tags: css, transform, opera

I just downloaded the latest version of Opera.  Is there a way to make my elements (div tags) rotate with CSS3?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this document on the Opera Developer Community](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-transitions-and-2d-transforms/), something like this should work:

```
div {
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

Don't forget properties for other browsers (`-moz-transform`, `-webkit-transform`) if you need cross-browser support!

Comment: Amen Brother... I just found the link too:  http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/cross-browser-rotation-transformation-with-css/

Many thanks.

Erik